# Chef - Notify an execute before resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a simple `execute[apt-update]` resource in an `apt` recipe:

```
execute "apt-update" do
  command "apt-get update"
  action :nothing
end
```

And I want to be able to notify it, only if a package needs to be installed. I was hoping for something like:

```
include_recipe "apt"

package "openssh-server" do
  action :install
  notifies :run, 'execute[apt-update]', :before
end
```

The `:before` isn't currently a valid timing, and [probably wont be any time soon](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2421)

It's something that is [possible with Puppet](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/metaparameter.html#before), and was wondering if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: What's the actual problem that you want to solve? Update all packages first? Or do you mean `apt-get update` instead of `upgrade`?

Comment: Ha, yeah sorry, meant `apt-get update` ... I've updated the question

Comment: What I now notice is that you already have a `include_recipe "apt"`. So everything should work without any notifications, shouldn't it?

Comment: it has `action :nothing` so that it doesn't run unless notified

Comment: No, I menat the `apt::default` recipe that you include in the second block. But not sure, if this is the community `apt` cookbook - likely not.

Comment: Nah it's not the community one :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functionality in question was added in Chef 12.6:
https://docs.chef.io/release_notes.html#what-s-new-in-12-6

So you can write code exactly like you pasted above now.

Comment: Awesome thanks ... Unfortunately can't change the accepted answer now Lol

Answer (score 4):

## Keeping the APT Cache Up-to-Date

While this is not an answer to your question, I can hopefully provide you an answer to your actual problem (which is a pretty common one btw.):

**The [apt](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apt) cookbook that you should include in your run list *before* you use the `package` resource will automatically pull the repos.**

In order to avoid pulling repos during every chef run, it by default pulls them only once per day, while this minimum delay can be configured via `node['apt']['periodic_update_min_delay']`.

Therefore, at least for the use cases I had during the last years with Chef, I think I never needed to notify a resource doing `apt-get update`. Even when adding an additional *apt* repository, this can easily be done as follows:

```rb
apt_repository 'security-ubuntu-multiverse' do
  uri        'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu'
  distribution 'trusty-security'
  components ['multiverse']
  deb_src 'true'
 end
```

The clever thing with the `apt_repository` resource is that it automatically triggers an `apt-get update` run.

## The Smell of Triggering a Resource To Run *Before*

*(Added with permission from original Author, contributed by [@Tensibai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3627607/tensibai))*

On why a `:before` is a false 'good idea' 99% of the time:

When you think about it on an isolated package install, it sounds the way to go, ask the package to notify an execute to run `apt-get update` before.

Now when you extend this to N packages (in 1 or more recipes), you will wish to ensure `apt-get update` has been run before each package if it has to be installed.

Here's come the dragons, how many time would we call `apt-get update` ? with a straight `:before, :immediately` it will be called N times, once before each package, that's silly but could be your wish.

You may object it should be done only once, and as `:delayed` it should be queued up, but when ? At compile time we don't know if the package will need to be installed or not, this suppose adding a new 'compile' phase to test those resources and build the 'pre-notification' queue.

That's part of what Puppet does, and where it comes a problem when you wish complete control over execution order.

More details on this [here](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-2421)

## The New `:immediately_before` Resource

Now I said why it should be used sparingly, here the good news:
A new `:immediately_before` is on its way into chef in a near future per [rfc-154](https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/pull/154) and this [PR](https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/4062)

Comment: worth a complement (Abandonned my answer as yours covers 98%): What would be the purpose of a `:before` notification here ? it would obviously be immediate, and so if there's 4 packages to install in 4 recipes `apt-get update` would be called 4 times, that's part of why `:before` is usually a  false good idea

Comment: Thx @Tensibai for the comment. Feel free to edit and add the remaining 2% ;-)

Comment: This does seem a better way to do it ... Although I'm still in the stage where I want to create all my cookbooks from scratch ... I think I'll rip the apt cookbook apart and find out how it does the daily update :D ... Thanks

Comment: @StephenKing Sorry, turned into a long addition, and found updated information at the same time :)

Comment: Tensibai, well written, thanks! Stretch, try to avoid reinventing the wheel ;-)

Comment: @Tensibai according to the PR, it's `:before`, not `:immediately_before`, isn't it?

Comment: @StephenKing I'm sticking with creating my own cookbooks for now because I made the mistake a couple of days ago by running `knife cookbook site install nagios` Lol ... It installs about 47 dependencies, including Windows dependencies ... I like the fine grain control you can get from creating your own :D Thanks a lot for your answer though, I managed to get the little bit from the `apt` cookbook that I needed to only update it once a day :D ... Still, hoping for the introduction of the `:immediately_before` timing ... As the question points out, "If Puppet can do it, why not Chef"

Comment: @Stretch for the same reason chef is born, Puppet has a very opiniated way on rearranging steps on your behalf, sometimes ending on breaked order at end. (that's when I stepped over from puppet to chef, didn't follow much but I doubt the core system has changed that much)

Comment: @Stephen well the RFC seems pointing a :before but the code implements :immediately_before, as it is not already merged, there's chances it will change. (I would favor the immediately_before as I found it more clear on what will happen)

Comment: @Tensibai Yeah I think they changed it last minute to `:before` because of demand, and probably more human readable. I moved to using Chef for career reasons, but I'm starting to like it. Both Chef and Puppet have their merits and de-merits, still can't decide which is better.

Comment: @Stretch of course there's pro and cons in both. My two main reasons to choose Chef was the open DSL allowing custom code and the windows support in the base open source offer ;) As usual, It's a matter of context for you an what suit your needs.

Comment: And FWIW I just notice I linked the same ticket as the question, where the RFC and PR are liked as last comment ;) (and I become to chatty here, better move to chat if you wish to discuss it more)

Comment: @StephenKing I was kinda sitting on the fence whether to accept it as an answer, because currently it doesn't answer the original question, but seeing as it's an excellent explanation as to why it's not yet available, and possible future implementation, you get my 'Green Tick Click' ... *Applauds* ... Sorry I don't have trophies to hand out

Comment: He he, thx. I hope your relief with the new before resource comes soon.